# BPP search: what does boosting correctness entail?

Tags: probabilistic-algorithms, search-problem

It is not really clear to me, how and if I can do boosting for correctness (or error reduction) on a [BPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPP_%28complexity%29) (bounded-error probabilistic polynomial-time) search problem. Can anyone of you explain me how it works?

With BPP search, I mean a problem that can have false positive-negative, correct solution, and no-solution. Here's a definition:

A probabilistic polynomial-time algorithm $A$ solves the search problem of the relation $R$ if

- for every $x ∈ S$, $Pr[A(x) ∈ R(x)] > 1 - μ(|x|)$
- for every $x ∉ SR$, $Pr[A(x) = \text{no-solution}] > 1 - μ(|x|)$

were $R(x)$ is the set of solution for the problem and $μ(|x|)$ is a negligible function (it is rare that it fails).

So now I would like to increase my probability of getting a good answer, how can I do it?

---

~ ".. boosting for correctness.." : a way to increase the probability of the algorithm (generally by multile runs of the probabilistic algorithm), i.e., when the problem have a solution then the algorithm likely return a valid one.

Comment: Make clear what BPP stands for (at least add a link), also explain what "boosting for correctness" means.

Comment: you got the definition wrong. For (standard) BPP, $\mu(x)=1/3$. Then to get a negligible $\mu$ one just performs repetitions of the algorithm and takes the majority of the answers. Due to [Chernoff bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound), the probability that the majority of the results are incorrect is negligibly small.

Comment: I think you actually make a very good point here: I think the boosting only works if your problem lies in $\mathbf{NP}$ (or $\mathbf{coNP}$ for the other error bound). This might be a widespread belief because most problems for which we develop $\mathbf{BPP}$ algorithms are also in $\mathbf{NP}$. As the relation between $\mathbf{NP}$ and $\mathbf{BPP}$ is not known, I guess that it is also not known whether this always works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the relation $R$ lies in the complexity class P (or even BPP), then boosting works by running your algorithm many times, and testing whether its output satisfies $R$. When $x \in S$, this fails with probability $\mu^N$, where $N$ is the number of times you run $A$. When $x \notin S$, this never fails. This way you can boost $\mu$ from $1-1/\mathrm{poly}(n)$ to $2^{-\mathrm{poly}(n)}$.

Edit: if $R$ is in BPP rather than P, with constant error probability $\mu$, then this approach doesn't work. You can decide whether $x \in S$ or not using the usual majority trick, but if $x \in S$, it's not clear how you'd find a correct witness whp.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but is not really clear why μ(x)=1/3, should not it decrease faster, on the relevand parameter x?

Comment: $\mu(x) = 1/3$ by definition. If $R \in P$ then $\mu$ can be boosted to $3^{-n^k}$ for any $k$ by just running the algorithm $n^k$ times.

Comment: but how can you say that "When x∉S, this never fails"?
this R is in BPP not in RP..

Thanks for reply

Comment: You're right, I was assuming that $R$ is in P.